# How to create a trigger that copies into another table the original and edited data from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I am using SQL Server and i am wondering if there is a way to create a trigger on a table which allows to copy its original data before an update and also copy its modified data after the update in another table?

If yes, how could i make the difference between both?

Thanks :)

---

@SouravA

```
create trigger SomeBeforeUpdateTrigger
on YourTable
before update
as
insert into SecondTable (ID, Name)
select ID, Name
from deleted; 
go
insert into SecondTable (ID, NewName)
select ID, Name
from inserted;
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that.

Comment: @jarlh But how to make the difference between original and edited data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, yes it is possible. You would basically need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

```
create trigger SomeBeforeUpdateTrigger
on YourTable
before update
as
insert into BeforeUpdate (ID, Name)
select ID, Name
from deleted; 
go
insert into AfterUpdate (ID, Name)
select ID, Name
from inserted;
```

The first statement will insert those rows into the table `BeforeUpdate` which are getting changed. The second will insert the new rows into the table `AfterUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks ! Moreover i have to insert both before and after update data in the same table.  So maybe i could use that : check above in the post

Comment: Sure, you can use the same table instead. Add a timestamp column too where you can map the `getdate()`.